# Spacy - Save custom pipeline

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to integrate a custom `PhraseMatcher()` component into my nlp pipeline in a way that will allow me to load the custom Spacy model without having to re-add my custom components to a generic model on each load.

How can I load a Spacy model containing custom pipeline components?

I create the component, add it to my pipeline and save it with the following:

```
import requests
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Doc, Span, Token

class RESTCountriesComponent(object):
    name = 'countries'
    def __init__(self, nlp, label='GPE'):
        self.countries = [u'MyCountry', u'MyOtherCountry']
        self.label = nlp.vocab.strings[label]
        patterns = [nlp(c) for c in self.countries]
        self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.matcher.add('COUNTRIES', None, *patterns)        
    def __call__(self, doc):
        matches = self.matcher(doc)
        spans = []
        for _, start, end in matches:
            entity = Span(doc, start, end, label=self.label)
            spans.append(entity)
        doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + spans
        for span in spans:
            span.merge()
        return doc

nlp = English()
rest_countries = RESTCountriesComponent(nlp)
nlp.add_pipe(rest_countries)
nlp.to_disk('myNlp')
```

I then attempt to load my model with,

```
nlp = spacy.load('myNlp')
```

But get this error message:

> KeyError: u"[E002] Can't find factory for 'countries'. This usually
>   happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a component name
>   that's not built in - for example, when constructing the pipeline from
>   a model's meta.json. If you're using a custom component, you can write
>   to `Language.factories['countries']` or remove it from the model meta
>   and add it via `nlp.add_pipe` instead."

I can't just add my custom components to a generic pipeline in my programming environment. How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you save out your model, spaCy will serialize all data and store a reference to your pipeline in the model's `meta.json`. For example: `["ner", "countries"]`. When you load your model back in, spaCy will check out the meta and initialise each pipeline component by looking it up in the so-called "factories": functions that tell spaCy how to construct a pipeline component. (The reason for that is that you usually don't want your model to store and eval arbitrary code when you load it back in – at least not by default.)

In your case, spaCy is trying to look up the component name `'countries'` in the factories and fails, because it's not built-in. The `Language.factories` are a simple dictionary, though, so you can customise it and add your own entries:

```
from spacy.language import Language
Language.factories['countries'] = lambda nlp, **cfg: RESTCountriesComponent(nlp, **cfg)
```

A factory is a function that receives the shared `nlp` object and optional keyword arguments (config parameters). It then initialises the component and returns it. If you add the above code *before* you load your model, it should load as expected.

### More advanced approaches

If you want this taken care of automatically, you could also ship your component *with* your model. This requires wrapping it as a Python package using the [`spacy package`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#package) command, which creates all required Python files. By default, the `__init__.py` only includes a function to load your model – but you can also add custom functions to it or use it to add entries to spaCy's factories.

As of `v2.1.0` (currently available as a [nightly version](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/releases/tag/v2.1.0a0) for testing), spaCy will also support providing pipeline component factories [via Python entry points](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/2348). This is especially useful for production setups and/or if you want to modularise your individual components and split them into their own packages. For example, you could create a Python package for your countries component and its factory, upload it to PyPi, version it and test it separately. In its `setup.py`, your package can define the spaCy factories it exposes and where to find them. spaCy will be able to detect them automatically – all you need to do is install the package in the same environment. Your model package could even require your component package as a dependency so it's installed automatically when you install your model.

Answer (score 3):

This same issue came up for me and these are the steps I used:

- 1) Save pipeline after running notebook containing all the different nlp pipeline components e.g. nlp.to_disc('pipeline_model_name')
- 2) Build Package saved pipeline with Spacy: run `python setup.py sdist` in this directory.
- 3) Pip install the created package
- 4) Put custom components in `__init__.py` file of package as instructed above
- 4) Load pipeline with:

  - **Import  spacy**
  - **nlp = spacy_package.load()**