# Adding a Retokenize pipe while training NER model

Tags: spacy

I am currenly attempting to train a NER model centered around Property Descriptions. I could get a fully trained model to function to my liking however, I now want to add a retokenize pipe to the model so that I can set up the model to train other things.

From here, I am having issues getting the retokenize pipe to actually work. Here is the definition:

```
def retok(doc):
    ents = [(ent.start, ent.end, ent.label) for ent in doc.ents]
    with doc.retokenize() as retok:
        string_store = doc.vocab.strings
    for start, end, label in ents:
        retok.merge(
                doc[start: end],
                attrs=intify_attrs({'ent_type':label},string_store))
    return doc
```

i am adding it into my training like this:

```
nlp.add_pipe(retok, after="ner")
```

and I am adding it into the Language Factories like this:

```
Language.factories['retok'] = lambda nlp, **cfg: retok(nlp)
```

The issue I keep getting is "AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'ents'". Now I am assuming I am getting this error because the parameter that is being passed through this function is not a doc but actually the NLP model itself. I am not really sure to get a doc to flow into this pipe during training. At this point I don't really know where to go from here to get the pipe to function the way I want.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially use the built-in `merge_entities` pipeline component: https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities

The example copied from the docs:

```
texts = [t.text for t in nlp("I like David Bowie")]
assert texts == ["I", "like", "David", "Bowie"]

merge_ents = nlp.create_pipe("merge_entities")
nlp.add_pipe(merge_ents)

texts = [t.text for t in nlp("I like David Bowie")]
assert texts == ["I", "like", "David Bowie"]
```

If you need to customize it further, the current implementation of `merge_entities` (v2.2) is a good starting point:

```
def merge_entities(doc):
    """Merge entities into a single token.

    doc (Doc): The Doc object.
    RETURNS (Doc): The Doc object with merged entities.

    DOCS: https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities
    """
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for ent in doc.ents:
            attrs = {"tag": ent.root.tag, "dep": ent.root.dep, "ent_type": ent.l
abel}
            retokenizer.merge(ent, attrs=attrs)
    return doc
```

P.S. You are passing `nlp` to `retok()` below, which is where the error is coming from:

```
Language.factories['retok'] = lambda nlp, **cfg: retok(nlp)
```

See a related question: [Spacy - Save custom pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51412095/461847)

Comment: This is great. I must have breezed over this because i didn't immediately put together that NER produces entities. After adding this i get a new issue though.    
 
 

`gold = GoldParse.from_annot_tuples(doc, zip(*gold.orig_annot))
  File "gold.pyx", line 540, in spacy.gold.GoldParse.from_annot_tuples
ValueError: need more than 6 values to unpack`

Comment: There's not quite enough context to be sure, but I think that's a known bug. It should really be a separate question, or search the issue tracker first. (The answer is probably upgrade and don't use `gold_preproc`.)

Comment: could you clarify what i am upgrading? i am using the most current version of spacy. Additionally, the train code does not appear to be referencing gold_preproc.

Comment: This is getting pretty off-topic: a new question or a bug report would be better!